# mock or stub for chained call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

```
protected int parseExpire(CacheContext ctx) throws AttributeDefineException {
    Method targetMethod = ctx.getTargetMethod();
    CacheEnable cacheEnable = targetMethod.getAnnotation(CacheEnable.class);
    ExpireExpr cacheExpire = targetMethod.getAnnotation(ExpireExpr.class);
    // check for duplicate setting
    if (cacheEnable.expire() != CacheAttribute.DO_NOT_EXPIRE && cacheExpire != null) {
        throw new AttributeDefineException("expire are defined both in @CacheEnable and @ExpireExpr");
    }
    // expire time defined in @CacheEnable or @ExpireExpr
    return cacheEnable.expire() != CacheAttribute.DO_NOT_EXPIRE ? cacheEnable.expire() : parseExpireExpr(cacheExpire, ctx.getArgument());
}
```

that is the method to test ,

```
Method targetMethod = ctx.getTargetMethod();
CacheEnable cacheEnable = targetMethod.getAnnotation(CacheEnable.class);
```

I have to mock three CacheContext,Method and CacheEnable.
Is there any idea to make the test case much simpler?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Mockito [can handle chained stubs](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

```
Foo mock = mock(Foo.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

// note that we're stubbing a chain of methods here: getBar().getName()
when(mock.getBar().getName()).thenReturn("deep");

// note that we're chaining method calls: getBar().getName()
assertEquals("deep", mock.getBar().getName());
```

AFAIK, the first method in the chain returns a mock, which is set up to return your value on the second chained method call.

Mockito's authors note that this should *only be used for legacy code*. A better thing to do otherwise is to push the behavior into your CacheContext and provide any information it needs to do the job itself. The amount of information you're pulling from CacheContext suggests that your class has [feature envy](https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/docs/Feature-Envy.md).

Comment: Well, Szczepan created Mockito because he saw me and some others rolling out our own mocks by hand instead of using EasyMock, and decided that mocks should work better for BDD - so obviously I prefer Mockito! But he forked EasyMock to do it, so for that reason, yes, EasyMock is great. We stand on the shoulders of giants...

Comment: This is interesting and I upvoted. But can't you simply use `Foo foo=mock(Foo.class); Bar bar=mock(Bar.class); when(foo.getBar()).thenReturn(bar); when(bar.getName()).thenReturn("deep")'`. To my eyes, that is easy to read and does not require understanding the concept of "DEEP" stubbing. (Btw, I like Mockito.)

Comment: Yep. I think this could be useful though if your next legacy code step is to move one of the methods to the right place (which eliminates the problem entirely but would cause this way of doing things to need large amounts of fixing afterwards).

Comment: But is it always feature envy? I have a dto tree that organizes my large data in memory. I have other classes that read data from this tree and do operations on them. To test them, I need to mock the dto - BTW, I can create the actual dto, but it is just as cumbersome - deep stubbing really helps me in this case. Do I miss anything here? can I make my code better?

Comment: @Arash It isn't always feature envy. In your case I'd look at creating some kind of MVP pattern, where a model is presented in a particular DTO to the persistence layer. Now you have a rich object, not just a DTO. Patterns like MVP are as applicable to persistence as to UIs!

Comment: This doesn't work if one of the chain returns a generic type. Did anyone else face this issue?

Comment: @VivekKothari Maybe submit it to the Mockito team? https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues

Comment: Feture envy definition was moved here: https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/docs/Feature-Envy.md

Comment: @Sammi This looks like a gorgeous little tool; I haven't come across Reek before. And what a fantastic name... :D

Comment: @Lunivore Could you point to some official source where the authors state that deep stubs only should be used for legacy code?

Comment: @Magnilex It is actually *in* the official source. As in, the source code. "Please note that in most scenarios a mock returning a mock is wrong." Also: WARNING: This feature should rarely be required for regular clean code! Leave it for legacy code. Mocking a mock to return a mock, to return a mock, (...), to return something meaningful hints at violation of Law of Demeter or mocking a value object (a well known anti-pattern).
     https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mockito/Mockito.java (most of it at line 1393).

Comment: @Lunivore Fair point. Although around one level of doing so might be acceptable, but I understand that the method is probably widely abused. I wonder if it is a candidate for deprecation.

Comment: @Magnilex Wrapping tests around legacy code is an important part of being able to refactor it safely. There's nothing wrong with having it as an intermediate step to a cleaner codebase.

Comment: @Magnilex Having said that, I'm actually using RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS at the moment for backing a complex interface with some methods that forward to an internal hashmap that I don't want to be mocked, using Kotlin and the "by" keyword... so maybe there are more uses for it these days.

Comment: I ended up using `RETURNS_SELF`, since the official docs discourage `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS `

Comment: @Ming The `RETURNS_SELF` is useful if you're creating builders (which normally return themselves so that you can keep adding things). In OP's case it doesn't match the signature or intent. `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` is the right thing to use, especially if the intent is to wrap something in a test while refactoring. The docs don't actually discourage `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`; they discourage the anti-pattern that necessitates it in the first place (violation of the Law of Demeter, aka feature envy).

Comment: How to achieve this with @Mock annotation?

Comment: @RuifengMa I'm guessing from this documentation that it would be 
@Mock(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) - give it a go and let us know!  https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/Mock.html

Answer (score 11):

Just in case you are using Kotlin. MockK doesn't say anything about chaining being a bad practice and easily allows you to do [this](https://mockk.io/#Chained-calls).

```
val car = mockk<Car>()

every { car.door(DoorType.FRONT_LEFT).windowState() } returns WindowState.UP

car.door(DoorType.FRONT_LEFT) // returns chained mock for Door
car.door(DoorType.FRONT_LEFT).windowState() // returns WindowState.UP

verify { car.door(DoorType.FRONT_LEFT).windowState() }

confirmVerified(car)
```

Comment: Yep, great thing, really helps to reduce amount of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on [Lunivore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7932208/12724430), for anyone injecting a mocked bean, use:

```
@Mock(answer=RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
private Foo mockedFoo;
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion to make your test case simpler is to refactor your method.

Anytime I find myself having trouble testing a method, it's a code smell for me, and I ask why is it hard to test. And if code is hard to test, it's probably hard to use and maintain.

In this case it's because you have a method chain that goes several levels deep. Perhaps pass in ctx, cacheEnable, and cacheExpire as parameters.

Comment: Yes, but these fields are from the aop context at runtime, it is hard to simplify the environment.

Comment: TThere are techniques to do this in JMockit.  You can mock fields into your objects simualting AOP field injection. Or you can use deencapsulation techniques initializing provate fields with mocked instances

Comment: Can you provide an example @doug, please?

Answer (score 2):

I  found JMockit  easier to use ans switched to it completely. See test cases using it:

https://github.com/ko5tik/andject/blob/master/src/test/java/de/pribluda/android/andject/ViewInjectionTest.java

Here I mock away Activity base class, which is coming from Android SKD and completely 
stubbed.   With JMockit you can mock thingis tha are final, private, abstract  or whatever else.

In your testcase it would look like:

```
public void testFoo(@Mocked final Method targetMethod, 
                    @Mocked  final CacheContext context,
                    @Mocked final  CacheExpire ce) {
    new Expectations() {
       {
           // specify expected sequence of infocations here

           context.getTargetMethod(); returns(method);
       }
    };

    // call your method
    assertSomething(objectUndertest.cacheExpire(context))
```

Comment: Note that JMockit has an annotation specifically for chained calls: `@Cascading`. Also, in cases like this you probably want to use `NonStrictExpectations` instead of `Expectations`, assuming the calls to mocked methods don't need to be verified.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this annotation ;) Gone simplify my unit tests