# Mocking chained method calls using mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, junit, mockito

I need to mock this:

```
 void handleCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<List<String>> event) {
    Element cellElement = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast();
 }
```

I am doing this:

```
CellPreviewEvent<List<String>> cellPreviewEvent = Mockito.mock(
        CellPreviewEvent.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
Element cellElement = Mockito.mock(Element.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
EventTarget eventTarget = Mockito.mock(EventTarget.class);
  Mockito.when(cellPreviewEvent.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast()).thenReturn(cellElement);
```

And I am getting following error:

```
testHandleCellPreview(client.view.MyViewTest)java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent.getEventTarget(NativeEvent.java:137)
    atclient.view.MyViewTest.testHandleCellPreview(MyViewTest.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I've also seen, the same question below:

[mock or stub for chained call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7926891/768894)
Can anybody please point out what I am missing?

Thanks,
Mohit

Comment: what is at line 76 of `testHandleCellPreview`? What version of GWT are you using?

Comment: **Don't mock type you don't own!** It's a bad thing, for example : if the external type changes the behavior you won't see it in your test, if the external type is refactored or something you'll have to rewrite all your test. You should instead write an anti-corruption layer (or wrappers, or bridges) that you will only test with integration tests. Also above code shows that you are breaking the **Demeter Law**, you should instead practice the **tell, don't ask** principle. Hope that will helps :)

Comment: @John line# 76 is the call to my method(under test). And I am using GWT 2.5

Comment: @Brice Disagree regarding don't mock type you don't own. In a unit test, all non-trivial (non-bean) classes that the class under test interacts with should be mocked. Once you start testing the interaction of multiple classes (owned or not) you are doing valuable testing that is not "unit" testing (integration, feature, whatever you want to call it). Totally agree on the use of wrappers or bridges (facade pattern).

Comment: @JohnB Well this is a lifesaver principle, you can cross the line, but it can bite you back. The only thing where I would mock a type I dont own is to verify interaction, but **never ever to stub** this external type. Actually I had a very pleasant surprise to see that _Nat Pryce_ and _Steeve Freeman_ don't recommand it either in their book **Growing Object Oriented Software Guided by Tests** (a must read in my opinion). Also I took the _Anti-Corruption Layer_ term from _Eric Evans_ **DDD** book (which happens to be a must read too).

Comment: @Brice Thinking through what you have said further, I agree with you with one exception. In the case where the external type has side-effects that would not be desirable in a unit test (networking interactions being an example - wouldn't want to hit a Rest Service as part of a unit test). Or in your reading to you find a different workaround for this?

Comment: @JohnB But that wouldn't be a mock, if it were executing real stuff ;) By stubbing a non owned type I meant to simulate the behavior of this type. For example suppose I want to mock a SortingAlgorithm.sort() that is coded by other guys, if for some reason the algorithm changes between versions I won't see it in my test, because I stubbed it. And I will have a boom in production while I was thinking everything was all green.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are attempting to execute GWT code outside of a client browser environment. GWT is designed to be converted to JavaScript and run on a browser. I am not sure it will work otherwise.

I noticed that line 137 of `NativeEvent` appears to be `DomImpl.impl.eventGetTarget`. This leads me to believe that `DomImpl.impl` is `null`.

I found the following by looking into the code:

```
45  public static <T> T create(Class<?> classLiteral) {
46     if (sGWTBridge == null) {
47       /*
48        * In Production Mode, the compiler directly replaces calls to this method
49        * with a new Object() type expression of the correct rebound type.
50        */
51       throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
52           "ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!  It cannot be called, "
53               + "for example, from server code.  If you are running a unit test, "
54               + "check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that GWT.create() "
55               + "is not called from within an initializer or constructor.");
56     } else {
57       return sGWTBridge.<T> create(classLiteral);
58     }
59   }
```

Have you extended `GWTTestCase`

Comment: No I am using usual 'extends TestCase'. I am using Mockito. http://code.google.com/p/mockito/

Answer (score -1):

You need to set mocked objects again in parent entity. So that at run - time , it uses the mocked objects.

```
cellPreviewEvent.setCellElement(cellElement);
cellPreviewEvent.setEventTarget(eventTarget);
```

Complete code would look like:

```
CellPreviewEvent<List<String>> cellPreviewEvent = Mockito.mock(
        CellPreviewEvent.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
Element cellElement = Mockito.mock(Element.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
EventTarget eventTarget = Mockito.mock(EventTarget.class);
cellPreviewEvent.setCellElement(cellElement);
cellPreviewEvent.setEventTarget(eventTarget);
  Mockito.when(cellPreviewEvent.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast()).thenReturn(cellElement);
```

Comment: I don't add cells to my DataGrid (GWT). I am not using custom cells. :(

Comment: These methods are undefined for cellPreviewEvent. To know more see here: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/view/client/CellPreviewEvent.html

Comment: I believe I won't be able to mock it this way as getEventTarget() Method is FINAL & RETURN_DEEP_STUBS doesn't support final methods or final classes.