# One when for two consecutive method calls in Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

When I'm writing unit tests with Mockito, I'll often find that I call a getter on one of my injected mocks, and then call a method off the returned object.

So far, I've done that something like this:

```
    @Mock
    private Randomizer r;
    @Mock
    private Random random;
    @InjectMocks
    private NodeGenerator ng = new NodeGenerator();

    @Test
    public void nodeIsDuplicate() {

        when(r.getRandom()).thenReturn(random);
        when(random.nextInt(2)).thenReturn(1);
        [...]
    }
```

But it seems like such a waste to have to mock out the random and set up a second when for it. Is there some way to make my when statement more like:

```
when(r.getRandom().nextInt(2)).thenReturn(1);
```

Without having to mock out the random, so I can do it all on one line with just my Randomizer mock?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926891/mock-or-stub-for-chained-call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want Mockito's [One liner stubs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#24).

Edit:

Upon closer inspection that may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it can reduce some of that boiler plate code for you.

Wat you are looking for is, indeed as the comment suggests, [deep stubs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS).

For your example it would be :

```
Randomizer randomizer = mock(Randomizer.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

when(randomizer.getRandom().nextInt(2)).thenReturn(1);
```

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out based off the comment's link. Actually, all I need to do is add: @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) for the annotation and it magically works! Pretty cool.

Comment: Do heed the cautionary warning about violating Demeter's Law.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's just a personal project, though, so I'm sometimes ignoring some OO design principles I would follow if I were coding for work.

Comment: In this specific case I guess if I wanted to replace the Randomizer's random number generator with one that isn't Java's Random class, that would cause a pretty big issue, but I can't imagine wanting to replace it anyway.

Comment: If your unit doesn't use Randomizer, other than to get Random, why don't you inject the Random instance, rather than the Randomizer.