# Avoiding cast in bytecode on list elements with Powermockito 1.5

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I use powermock with mockito because I need its static method mocking feature.
I am trying to upgrade Powermock from 1.4.9 to 1.5.6 and mockito from 1.9 to 1.9.5 because PowerMockRunner in 1.4.9 breaks unexpectedly under particular condition in my IDE and the problem is solved in 1.5 version which in turn needs the latter to be upgraded.
When I define the following in my unit test

```
when(cart.getProducts().get(0)).thenReturn(productMock);
```

a ClassCastException is raised from Stub type to actual list element type. `cart` is a deep stub mock.
Decompiling the byte code, I notice that it tries to cast as in example below

```
org/mockito/Mockito.when((com/shop/Product)cart.getProducts().get(0))
                   .thenReturn(productMock);
```

When decompiling the same code compiled with Powermock 1.4.12 I get

```
org/mockito/Mockito.when(cart.getProducts().get(0))
                   .thenReturn(productMock);
```

There is no attempt to cast `get(0)` result.
It breaks lot of my unit tests and I would like to know if there is any way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You must do it in 2 steps:

```
List<Product> products  = new ArrayList<>();
// add your product here with products.add()

when(cart.getProducts()).thenReturn(products);
```

You can also mock the ArrayList but that's not necessary.

Comment: Thx for your answer but adding the mock product or mocking the list is nearly the same effort and I would ideally like to keep the unit tests as is. I already tried to mock the list and was not satisfied as it would represent a substantial effort to change the whole code to comply with this.

Comment: ok but notice that chained mocking such as this is not right and won't work for any other case also

Comment: Chained mocking does not work even if my mock returns deep stubs ? Because the case I presented seems to work in many unit tests in the code.

Comment: It seems like they're really working.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926891/mock-or-stub-for-chained-call

Comment: Actually it seems so. Do you know any mean to avoid the cast with PowerMockito 1.5+ versions ?

Comment: isnt it possible to use mockito's "when" instead of PowerMockito's?

Comment: It's Mockito's. If you read my decompilation highlights, you notice that it's Mockito's `when` that is used. I'm just annoyed by the cast made by PowerMockito as it forces me to code deep mock for generics.