# How to mock continuous called method in junit with mokito?

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso

For example.

I have a class "MyClass"

```
MyClass {
           ArrayList<String> as;
           public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(){
               return as;
              }
        }
```

In my code I have:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
String a = myClass.getArrayList().get(0);
```

In my test code, I want to mock MyClass and make String "a" equals to "123".
So I try:

```
MyClass myClass = mock(MyClass.class);
when(myClass.getArrayList().get(0)).thenReturn("123");
```

but this does not work. Any one know how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mock or stub for chained call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926891/mock-or-stub-for-chained-call)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
MyClass myClass = mock(MyClass.class);
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("123");
when(myClass.getArrayList()).thenReturn(arrayList);
```

The problem is that in your code you are mocking the array, not the "myClass".
myClass only knows about getArrayList, it does not know anything about how you interact with it after.