# How to mock method chaining using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have a method which has below line of code.

```
getRequestedCapabilities(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Capabilities capabilities = mapper.readValue(new 
 File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(jsonFilePath).getFile()), Capabilities.class);

}
```

In my test method I have prepared a DTO(capabilities) which  mapper.readValue() needs to return when it is invoked.

```
Mockito.when(mapper.readValue(Mockito.mock(File.class),Mockito.eq(Capabilities.class))).thenReturn(capabilities);
```

But I am getting an exception saying invalid use of matchers.
Can you please suggest how can I do this? Here the issue is how should I mock the parameters that is passed to mapper.readValue method which has method invocation chaining.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mock or stub for chained call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926891/mock-or-stub-for-chained-call)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply specify that if `readValue` receives any parameters then it will return `capabilities` object. Something like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
Mockito.when(mapper.readValue(any(), any())).thenReturn(capabilities);
```

But if you want to be more specific with your mock recording, you could specify which type of parameters it should be called with. Like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
Mockito.when(mapper.readValue(any(File.class), any(Capabilities.class))).thenReturn(capabilities);
```

UPDATE:
You can set the value of the file path manually. In the end, in unit tests you can and should declare any value in your test directly. Otherwise your test is not unit test anymore, given that you are interacting with other components.

Comment: If i directly give the path of file, It is able to mock by the approach you suggested.            `code` Capabilities capabilities = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\Users\\krp2\\xACT Codebase\\Symphony-SDK\\system-starter-sdk\\"
                    + "src\\capabilityregistrationrequest.json"), Capabilities.class); `code`     but if i use method invocation chaining as given in question, it is not able to mock.Getting null pointer exception

Comment: Which method is the one returning `null` in your method chain?

Comment: You probably don't have that file in you test resources.

Comment: Yes. jsonFilePath variable has the file location and this is loaded through a property file like shown below.        @Value("${application.capabilities.json.path}")
    private String                            jsonFilePath;                                            But property is not loaded while executing junits. Any suggestions?

Comment: Using `getClassLoader().getResource()` should work. Just make sure you have that json file inside your `main/test/resources' folder.

Comment: no.. since jsonFilePath  atttribute is null, it is effectively getClassLoader().getResource(null). Need a way where It can pick the jsonFilePath from property file.@Value("${application.capabilities.json.path}") private String jsonFilePath

Answer (score 0):

```
Mockito.when(mapper.readValue(Mockito.mock(File.class),Mockito.eq(Capabilities.class))).thenReturn(capabilities);
```

It's coming from Mockito.mock, when using parameters matchers all parameters must be matchers. You should then replace `Mockito.mock(File.class)` with `Mockito.any(File.class)` or `Mockito.eq(a properly initialized mock)`