# Kotlin-mockk chain call

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockk

I am trying to perform a chain call within my unit test using the mockk library within Kotlin. Below is my code:

```
@MockK
lateinit var crypto: Crypto

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)
}

@Test
fun testCryptoFunc() {
    // Given
    // When
    every { crypto.sayHello() } returns "gg" // This works
    every { crypto.sayHelloTwice("w").sayHello() } returns "gg" //sayHello() is unresolved

    // Then
    //val c = crypto.sayHelloTwice("ss")
    //print("rr")
}
```

And my implementation code:

```
fun sayHello(): String {
    return "hello"
}

fun sayHelloTwice(a: String): String {
    return sayHello() + a
}
```

I am trying to stub the inner call (sayHello()) but I am getting unresolved reference error. According to the Mockk documentation for chain calls, it says this should be valid.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding (but running into the compilation error). Tried restarting the IDE. Tried invalidating caches and restarting.

Is there anything that I'm missing/doing wrong?

References:

https://mockk.io/#chained-calls

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54347784/1342086

Comment: Strings are not mockable

Comment: I may be too naiive to realize but I was able to mock the sayHello() properly. Regardless, even if I change the return type for these methods to data classes, it's still running into the same issue.

Comment: Weird, can you submit github issue with logback TRACE level enabled logs

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here.

First, in a unit test, you shouldn't be testing a mock. You should be testing the concrete class. Otherwise you're just testing Mockk works as expected. So this will be a better test:

```
class Test {
    private lateinit var crypto: Crypto

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        crypto = Crypto()
    }

    @Test
    fun testCryptoFunc() {
        // Given
        val textToAdd = "gg"
        val expected = "hello$textToAdd"

        // When
        val actual = crypto.sayHelloTwice(textToAdd)

        // Then
        assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }
}
```

But let's say you want to mock `Crypto` as part of another test. Your `sayHelloTwice` function returns a String. a String doesn't have a `sayHello` function. One way to approach this is to make `sayHello` and `sayHelloTwice` extension functions on `String`. Then, you can stub `sayHelloTwice`. Once it returns a value, you can stub `sayHello` to process that value. Remember `sayHelloTwice` won't really be calling `sayHello`, since `sayHelloTwice` is now a stub. So you would have to call `sayHello` yourself:

```
class Test {
    @MockK
    lateinit var crypto: Crypto

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)
    }

    @Test
    fun testCryptoFunc() {
        with (crypto) {
            // Given
            every { "tt".sayHelloTwice("aa") } returns "mm"
            every { "mm".sayHello() } returns "success"

            // When
            val c = "tt".sayHelloTwice("aa").sayHello()

            // Then
            println(c)
        }
    }
}

class Crypto {
    fun String.sayHello(): String = "hello$this"

    fun String.sayHelloTwice(a: String): String =
        "$this$a".sayHello()
}
```