# How to mock chained method?

Tags: junit, java-8, mocking

I am writing unit test cases for one of the application class.Since all the code within the class is written in java8 its bit tricky to write test cases for it. I stuck with the situation where i need to mock method chaining.

```
@Override
public Single<MetadataManagerDeleteAttributeResponseV1> processEvent(
        Context context, MetadataManagerDeleteAttributeV1 event) {

    Database worldviewDatabase = context.client().database();

    String primaryKey = "metadata-manager:attribute:v1.json" + SCHEMA_CONNECTOR + event.getId();

    System.out.println(worldviewDatabase.deleteOne(primaryKey, WriteContext.builder().build()).map(deleteResultTry->deleteResultTry.get().ids()));

    //database object is of type single<try<deleteTry>>>
    return worldviewDatabase
            .deleteOne(primaryKey, WriteContext.builder().build())
            .map(deleteResultTry -> handleResponse(deleteResultTry, primaryKey))
            .map(Try::get);
}

public Try<MetadataManagerDeleteAttributeResponseV1> handleResponse(
        Try<DeleteResult> result, String primaryKey) {
   return result
           .filter(res -> !res.ids().isEmpty())
           .flatMap(res -> Try.fromOptional(res.ids().stream().findFirst()))
           .map(id -> {
               var response = new MetadataManagerDeleteAttributeResponseV1();
                   return response.withId(id.split(SCHEMA_CONNECTOR)[1]);
           }).mapException(e -> handleError(e, primaryKey));
}

private HttpCodedException handleError(Throwable error, String primaryKey) {
    if (error instanceof NoSuchElementException) {
        logger.warn("DeleteAttributeMetadataManagerV1Handler: object with " + primaryKey + " does not exist");
        return new HttpCodedException(HandlerErrorCode._404_NOT_FOUND,
               "object with " + primaryKey + " does not exist");
    } else {
        logger.error("DeleteAttributeMetadataManagerV1Handler error occurs: " + error.getMessage());
        return new HttpCodedException(HandlerErrorCode._500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "error occurs during"
                + " deleting object with " + primaryKey + ": " + error.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I dont know how to mock the following lines of code

```
return worldviewDatabase
                .deleteOne(primaryKey, WriteContext.builder().build())
                .map(deleteResultTry -> handleResponse(deleteResultTry, primaryKey))
                .map(Try::get);
```

I want to know what approach i can take to mock all the methods chained together in one statment.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926891/mock-or-stub-for-chained-call

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide method chain call into small parts.
for example:

```java
void yourMethod(SomeObject someObject)
{
    someObject.someMethod1().someMethod2().someMethod3();
}
```

Test:

```java
@Mock
SomeObject someObject;
when(someObject.someMethod1()).thenReturn(someObject2);
when(someObject2.someMethod2()).thenReturn(someObject3);
when(someObject3.someMethod3()).thenReturn(someObject4);
```

Please let me know if any query or issue.