# Mocking interface and final classes using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to unit tests for a class which contains a client and the client is retrieved from another library. This client is not part of initialization of class and is only created in one of the methods.

```
class Example {

    public Set<Data> getData(final String id) {
        final Client client = getClient();
        final Set<Data> data = client.getData(id);
        return data;
    }

// All of below needs mocking, so that I only have mocked Client.

    Client getClient() {
        return ClientFactory.getCloudAuthEnabledClient(
                CloudAuthConfig.builder()
                        .issuer(URI.create(CLOUDAUTH_URL))
                        .cloudAuthCredentials(getCloudAuthCredentials())
                        .build()
        );

    }

    private CloudAuthCredentials.RegionalAwsCredentials getCloudAuthCredentials() {
        return new CloudAuthCredentials.RegionalAwsCredentials(
                DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance(),
                CloudAuthRegion.from("region"));
    }
}
```

My unit test looks something like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleTest {
 
private Example example;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        example = new Example();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetData() {
       // Need to do mock client calls like this
       // when (client.getData("TestId").thenReturn(Set.of());
       assertEquals(example.getData("TestId"), emptySet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of explicitly creating the `client` in the class you are trying to test (`Example`), create a factory class and pass an instance to the `Example` constructor. Then you can mock that factory to return a mock `Client`.

Comment: I was initially creating a factory but want to avoid doing that as want to avoid consumers of the library initializing the client for whatever reasons. So, wanted to keep client private in a class.

Answer (score 0):

A mocking guideline is to avoid mocking classes you don't own. You can put a thin wrapper over them, or, if you need to create them inside the class, use a factory.

Your factory will wrap, and delegate to, the `ClientFactory` you've used here. To avoid allowing anyone else to create the client, make the only implementation of the factory's interface an anonymous inner class. You can inject that through dependency injection, or just chain constructors.

That will allow you to mock out the interface in your tests without allowing anyone else to access the actual factory.

Note your factory will also need to wrap the client to allow you to mock them both.

Note also that Mockito also [allows chain stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7932208/363592) which will make the mocking easier. I think this is actually a valid use case and not an antipattern.